# Get the encoded value of a character with current code page

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a database in SQL Server with COLLATION KR949_BIN2, which means that the codepage of this database is 949.
Is it possible to get the encoded value of a character based on the codepage in this database?
For example, the encoded value of character '좩' in codepage 949 is 0xA144, is there a SQL statement that I can get 0xA144 from char '좩' in this database?
Also, is there a way to insert '좩' into a column by its encoded value 0xA144?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something there's no `KR949_BIN2` returned by `sys.fn_helpcollations()`. Are you sure you're on Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake here. The collations is Korean_90_BIN2.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Character data is represented incorrectly when the code page of the client computer differs from the code page of the database in SQL Server 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/character-data-is-represented-incorrectly-when-the-code-page-of-the-client-computer-differs-from-the-code-page-of-the-database-in-sql-server-2005-4ec4ad9a-319d-2592-96b5-51b6b6abdead) I suspect that you're actually using the `Korean_Wansung_CI_AS` collation or something similar:

> **Method 2: Use an appropriate collation for the database**
>
> If you must use a non-Unicode data type, always make sure that the code page of the database and the code page of any non-Unicode columns can store the non-Unicode data correctly. For example, if you want to store code page 949 (Korean) character data, use a Korean collation for the database. For example, use the Korean_Wansung_CI_AS collation for the database.

That being the case, yes, you can see and insert `0xA144` as per the following example:

```sql
create table #Wansung (
  [Description] varchar(50),
  Codepoint varchar(50) collate Korean_Wansung_CI_AS
);

insert #Wansung ([Description], Codepoint)
  select 'U+C8A9 Hangul Syllable Jwaeg', N'좩';

insert #Wansung ([Description], Codepoint)
  select 'From Windows-949 encoding', 0xA144;

select [Description], Codepoint, cast(Codepoint as varbinary(max)) as Bytes, cast(unicode(Codepoint) as varbinary(max)) as UTF32
from #Wansung;
```

Which returns the results:

| Description | Codepoint | Bytes | UTF32 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U+C8A9 Hangul Syllable Jwaeg | 좩 | 0xA144 | 0x0000C8A9 |
| From Windows-949 encoding | 좩 | 0xA144 | 0x0000C8A9 |

Comment: I also have a question that I have tons of data with encoded format like 0xA144, how can I use bulk insert to load them into sql server with the correct values? It seems 0xA144 is treated as a common string in bulk insert.